after upgrade to 24.04, can not login to desktop, with console msg: NETDEV WATCHDOG: CPU: 6: transmit queue 0 timed out 10010 ms
After upgrade my ubuntu os to 24.04LTS, I am not able to login to the desktop. The system hangs in tty console, with below message on screen:
[   62.021353] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: NETDEV WATCHDOG: CPU: 6: transmit queue 0 timed out 10010 ms
[   62.021589] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: Reset adapter unexpectedly

But interestingly, I am able to access this system via ssh remotely. Though it is not enough for my daily work, I need x11 to GUI automation.
sudo dmesg shows below messages after the error message:
[   51.398489] fbcon: Taking over console
[   51.399265] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x75
[   62.021353] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: NETDEV WATCHDOG: CPU: 6: transmit queue 0 timed out 10010 ms
[   62.021589] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: Reset adapter unexpectedly
[   65.130188] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[ 6416.107318] systemd[1]: systemd 255.4-1ubuntu8.2 running in system mode (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT -GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY +P11KIT +QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -BPF_FRAMEWORK -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified)
[ 6416.107700] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[ 6416.188321] systemd[1]: Configuration file /run/systemd/system/netplan-ovs-cleanup.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
[ 6464.381198] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, quota, no debug enabled
[ 6464.393077] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[ 6464.405730] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
[ 6464.423864] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
[ 6464.448747] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 33738 MB/s
[ 6464.465746] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 33029 MB/s
[ 6464.482746] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 30985 MB/s
[ 6464.482749] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 33738 MB/s
[ 6464.499770] raid6: .... xor() 12542 MB/s, rmw enabled
[ 6464.499772] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
[ 6464.500636] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx
[ 6464.607143] Btrfs loaded, zoned=yes, fsverity=yes

What else can I check to figure out the root cause?
